# Spark SQL : filtering a table on records which appear in another table (two columns)?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql, filtering

I have several tables, and I would like to filter the rows in one of them, based on whether two columns are present in another table. The data on each table is as follows

Table1 : *one hash can be associated to several articles ; one article can be associated to several hashes*

| User Hash | Article Name |
| --- | --- |
| **Hash1** | **Article1** |
| Hash1 | Article2 |
| Hash2 | Article1 |
| **Hash3** | **Article3** |

Table2 : *each User Hash is uniquely associated to a User ID*

| User Hash | User ID |
| --- | --- |
| Hash1 | ID1 |
| Hash2 | ID2 |
| Hash3 | ID3 |

Table3 : *each Article Name is uniquely associated to an Article Number*

| Article Name | Article number |
| --- | --- |
| Article1 | Number1 |
| Article2 | Number2 |
| Article3 | Number3 |

Table4

| User ID | Article Number | OtherField |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | Number1 | Misc1 |
| ID2 | Number2 | Misc2 |
| ID3 | Number3 | Misc3 |

I would like to keep in Table4, only the lines for which the combination (User ID, Article Number) is present in Table1 (as User Hash and Article Name). So in this example, I would like to get the following result :

| User ID | Article Number | OtherField |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | Number1 | Misc1 |
| ID3 | Number3 | Misc3 |

What is the best way to do this in Spark SQL ? I have experimented using JOIN, but I am struggling with the fact that there are two conditions, which I would like both to be valid in a single row.

In my example, ID2 & Number2 are both in Table1, but not on the same row, so I want to filter this row out of Table4.

I hope the question is clear enough. Thanks in advance !

Comment: If you already turned the dataframes into to tables, you should consider using SQL's EXISTS subquery to filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a semi join:

```sql
select * 
from table4 
left semi join (
    select * from table1 
    join table2 using (`User Hash`) 
    join table3 using (`Article Name`)
) using (`User ID`, `Article Number`)

+-------+--------------+----------+
|User ID|Article Number|OtherField|
+-------+--------------+----------+
|    ID1|       Number1|     Misc1|
|    ID3|       Number3|     Misc3|
+-------+--------------+----------+
```

Or equivalently, `where exists`:

```
select * 
from table4 
where exists (
    select * from table1 
    join table2 using (`User Hash`) 
    join table3 using (`Article Name`) 
    where `User ID` = table4.`User ID` 
    and `Article Number` = table4.`Article Number`
)
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! is where exists generally more efficient than doing a semi join ?

Comment: They are actually identical. If you check the query plan using `explain`, you can confirm that they should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is just a bunch of joins:

```
select t2.userid, t3.articlenumber
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.userhash = t2.userhash join
     table3 t3
     on t3.articlename = t1.articlename;
```

Comment: no, that's not about joining the first 3 tables which i know how to do, but rather about filtering the values of Table4 based on whether the corresponding record exists in Table1.